# Slashing of a Validator's DOT Stake

Tags: substrate

Is the slashing of the DOT balance of a validator who has been determined to be a bad actor determined as a result of an algorithm, or, are humans evaluating the action and casting vote against them, or how is it handled?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are advanced programatic mechanism to penalize validator downtime & misbehavior. A good start would be reading

- polkadot.network wiki section on slashing: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/en/learn-staking#slashing
- Web 3 foundation wiki section on slashing mechanisms: https://w3f-research.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polkadot/slashing/amounts.html